# Python and BeautifulSoup4: finding certain text from the tables and parsing the very next table

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm facing quite a tricky problem while trying to fetch some data with BeautifulSoup.

I'd like to find all the tables that have certain text in them (in my example code 'Name:', 'City:' and 'Address:') and parse the text that is located in the very next table in the source code.

Page source code:

```
...
...
<td>Name:</td>
<td>John</td>
...
<td>City:</td>
<td>London</td>
...
<td>Address:</td>
<td>Bowling Alley 123</td>
...
...
```

I'd like to parse: "John", "London", "Bowling Alley 123"

Sorry I don't have any python code here to show my past effort, but it's because I've no idea where to start. Thanks!

Comment: Please post a more complete version of your HTML (with actual markup instead of "...").

Answer (score 0):

This is clunky, but depending on how your TD's are wrapped and how consistent your TD targets are, you should be able to find them, iterate through them and use findNextSibling() to get your data:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

html = """\
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Name:</td>
  <td>John</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>City:</td>
  <td>London</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Address:</td>
  <td>Bowling Alley 123</td>
 </tr>
</table>
"""

targets=["City:","Address:","Name:"]
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for tr in soup.findAll("tr"):
    for td in tr.findAll("td"):
        if td.text in targets:
            print td.findNextSibling().text
```

Bottom line, as long as you've got some sane/normal elements containing your TD's, using the NextSibling functions should get you where you're going.

Answer (score 0):

Whether this works properly is dependent on whether the HTML is properly formed, but will likely work even if there are extraneous newlines or other text.

```
import bs4

def parseCAN(html):
    b = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
    matches = ('City:', 'Address:', 'Name:')
    found = []
    elements = b.findAll('td')
    for n, e in enumerate(elements):
        if e.text not in matches:
            continue
        if n < len(elements) - 1:
            found.append(elements[n+1].text)
    return found
```